# How to make a vector from frequency of letters in a word in their corresponding position?

Tags: python, string, vector, text

Let me show you example first :

suppose one string is : 'ball'. so it's frequency is - b:1, a:1, l:2
another string        : 'bat'. so it's frequency is - b:1, a:1, t:1

for 'ball' vector will be : [1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
for 'bat' vector will be  : [1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0]

So, basically what I want is, length of all vectors will be 26. The value of any position will be sum of total number of all same letters (see example of 'ball', here 'b' is the 2nd letter of english alphabets, so it took 1 in 2nd place. Similarly for 'l' it is in the 12th place and it took value 2 as there are two 'l' in that word. All other positions got value 0 as there are no other letters. How it can be done in python? I have tried onehotencodig but this technique is not suitable for this job. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

To get the letters, we can use `string.ascii_lowercase` from the `string` module:

```
import string
string.ascii_lowercase
# 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
```

Create a dictionary to keep count of frequencies:

```
res = {x: 0 for x in list(string.ascii_lowercase)}
# {'a': 0, 'b': 0, 'c': 0, 'd': 0, 'e': 0, ....}
```

Iterate through the letters of your given string and increment the value in the dict, e.g.

```
txt = 'ball'
for ch in list(txt):
  res[ch] += 1
```

Convert the values in `res` to a list afterward to get the required format:

```
list(res.values())
# [1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

An alternative method:

Leverage the `ord` function, e.g.

```
ord('a') # value of 97
ord('a') - 97 # 0
```

Create a list of 26 0's:

```
res = [0] * 26
```

Iterate through the letters of your given string and increment the position in `res` (using `ord`) by 1:

```
for ch in list(txt):
   res[ord(ch) - 97] += 1
```

The above expects lowercase letters so if you have other characters (including uppercase) you will need to handle first.